# How to invoke a function when an element is created from a regular string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react component that on init, gets some elements by class (these elements are spans) and replaces them with textboxes. The elements are replaced by a regular string in HTML element format and has an event handler on that text.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";

function Test(props) {
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState(props.answers);

    useEffect(init, []);

    function init() {
        const temp = document.getElementById("tempHolder");
        temp.innerHTML = props.question;

        document.querySelectorAll(".blank--answer-request").forEach(el => {
            el.outerHTML = '<input type="text" class="blank--answer-request onfocusout="answerGiven" />';
        });
    }

    function answerGiven() {
        alert('test')
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't invoke the function I've set on onfocusout. If I replace the text with just a regular alert(), the alert gets called but the function inside the component (which is answerGiven) I cannot invoke on lost focus. I'm thinking its probably the scope but I don't know exactly what I need to do to be able to invoke the function I need.

Comment: I believe this is bad usage in reactjs. create a component for that dom and pass the function as props

Comment: Perhaps there is some missing context in this question, but why are you using react at all?

Comment: As @ksav mentions, it seems like there is a lot missing from this question. There is no use of `onFocusOut` or the `answersGiven` method in the code you provided, so it's not possible for us to see what causes your issue.

Comment: The reason I am doing this is I am using a 3rd Party component with which I have no control over. I cannot edit any code from this 3rd Party component and I need to be able to do exactly what I've described: which is call a function on onfocusout after replacing the components spans to textboxes.

Comment: if you really want to go down this route, (i'd recommend just forking the library and making it do what you want,) you can compose a regular component so you will have a react element of that input, then you can use `ReactDOMServer` like `const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<MyComp />);` i think so it'd work. right now, `answerGiven` wouldn't reference the internal scope of the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer is to opt out of react completely and do this with javascript alone.

```js
const CLASS_NAME = "blank--answer-request";
const SELECTOR = `.${CLASS_NAME}`;

document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR).forEach((el) => {
  const element = document.createElement("input");
  element.setAttribute("type", "text");
  element.setAttribute("value", "");
  element.setAttribute("class", CLASS_NAME);
  el.replaceWith(element);
});

document.addEventListener("focusout", (e) => {
  const {
    target
  } = e;
  if (target && target.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME)) {
    answerGiven(target);
  }
});

function answerGiven(target) {
  console.log(target);
}
```

```html
<span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
<span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
<span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
<span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
<span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
```

---

However, if you are still keen on using your existing react component, another answer is to use `ReactDOM.render` on each existing DOM node (passing the relevant props that each react component would need).

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
    <span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
    <span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
    <span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
    <span class="blank--answer-request"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
// index.js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import MyComp from "./MyComp";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);

const answers = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "buzz", "fizz"];

document.querySelectorAll(".blank--answer-request").forEach((el, i) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyComp val={i} answer={answers[i]} />, el);
});
```

---

```
// MyComp.js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function MyComp({ val, answer }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(`${val}`);
  const handleBlur = () => {
    if (!value) {
      return;
    }
    if (value.toLowerCase() === answer.toLowerCase()) {
      console.log("Correct!");
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Incorrect. The answer was: ${answer}`);
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit blazing-https-w35um]

Comment: The addEventListener was what I needed to do, thank you for providing me what I needed.

Comment: Updated with an approach that still makes use of your existing react component. Although I do prefer the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`node.replaceWith(newNode)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) instead of `node.outerHTML`.

```js
function answerGiven() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
function init() {
  //...
  document.querySelectorAll(".blank--answer-request").forEach(el => {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.className = el.className;
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
      // pass the current node triggered focusout and the event-data to objTest.answerGiven
      answerGiven(this, ...arguments)
    });
    el.replaceWith(input);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I can't use 'this' as I am using React functional component.

Comment: `this` inside the function-call during the `focusout` event is (by default) a reference to the input that triggered it. So it is accessible and usable. The reference to the function `answerGiven()` is also present, because it is inside same scope.